# RegEx. Is it possible to create search patterns that set different groups in different lines?

Tags: batch, regex, find-and-replace

I would like to have one search pattern that searches for different strings across different lines.

```
code:
M90
G90
G71
G75
G00
G97 S16000
G00 T1
G00 X123.4437 Y149.1445 Z-12.0
M12
G00
G01 Z1.5 F50.0
G01 X121.1585 Y147.6211 F60.0
...........

I would like to search for:

M90
G90
G71
G97 S16000 
F60.0
```

then set each of these patterns as individual groups, then Use a replace pattern to:

```
M90 delete
G90 keep
G71 replace with G21
G97 S10000 replace with M3 S10000
M12 replace with G64 P2
```

So, after processing:

```
G90
G21
G75
G00
M3 S16000
G00 T1
G00 X123.4437 Y149.1445 Z-12.0
G64 P2
G00
G01 Z1.5 F[50.0*60]
G01 X121.1585 Y147.6211 F[60.0*60]
```

At the moment I can easily search and replace individual patterns;
Ideally I would like one search script and one replace script doing all operations.

---

Btw FYI: I Found an open source c# [Ulility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8x9P.png) on the web that batch replaces strings in any file, so you can give it a search pattern and a replace pattern and Choose a folder where your files are and press GO..  It processes all files in the folder.

So, for example I use  `F(\d.*) to search and F[$1*60] to replace..`

Original Line:

```
G01 X121.1585 Y147.6211 F60.0
```

Processed line:

```
G01 X121.1585 Y147.6211 [F60.0*60]
```

RegExs are marvelous!

Thanks for checking this out..
Frank

Comment: What is the expected result from your example.

Comment: `G90`
`G21`
`G75`
`G00`
`M3 S16000`
`G00 T1`
`G00 X123.4437 Y149.1445 Z-12.0`
`G64 P2`
`G00`
`G01 Z1.5 F[50.0*60]`
`G01 X121.1585 Y147.6211 F[60.0*60]`

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1595489/edit), code in comment is unreadable.

Comment: Are you OK for a Notepad++ solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pure regex solution using Notepad++.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^(?:(G71)|(G97(?= S16000))|(M12)|M90)(\R?))|F([\d.]+)`
- Replace with: `(?1G21$4)(?2M3)(?3G64 P2$4)(?5F[$5*60])`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    ^                   # beginning of line
    (?:                 # non capture group
        (G71)               # group 1, G71
      |                 # OR
        (G97                # group 2, G97
            (?= S16000)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have S16000 after
        )                   # end group 2
      |                 # OR
        (M12)               # group 3, M12
      |                 # OR
        M90                 # M90
    )                   # end group
    (\R?)               # group 4, optional linebreak
)                   # end group
|                   # OR
F([\d.]+)           # F followed by digits and dot, save in group 5
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1                 # if group 1 exists,
    G21                 # replace with G21
    $4                  # ans linebreak
)                   # end if
(?2                 # if group 2 exists
    M3                  # replace with M3
)                   # end if
(?3                 # if group 3 exists
    G64 P2              # replace with G64 P2
    $4                  # and linebreak
)                   # end if
(?5                 # if group 5 exists
    F[$5*60]        # replace with F and [, content of group 5, *60, ]
)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks ::) you have experience, really cool.  Can you help me with an answer that works for .NET flavour?

Comment: Notepad++ uses Boost regex flavour, I don't know the one used in .NET. I'm not sure it supports conditionnal replacements.

Comment: Hi Toto I have a question: Why did you insert this on  your Replacement script:  $4                  # and linebreak

Comment: I have been trying to add a couple more groups to your script and I get some funky results. This is an example: (?:^(?:(G71)|(G97)|(M12)|(M22)M90)(\R?))|F([\d.]+) and replace (?1G21$4)(?2M3)(?3G64 P11 R4 S85 D0.03 F0.2$4)(?4M5)(?6F[$6*60])

Comment: @cheechy: `$4` is the content of group 4, it contains the linebreak that is in used within the file. When you insert new groups, they are all renumbered. You've added the group 4 `(M22)` then the linebreak is now contained in group **5** and you've missed a pipe between `(M22)` and `M90`, use `(M22)|M90`.

Comment: Thanks Toto. I think I understand better now. Also the symbol (\R?) in your script is group 4 and it is a match for newline. So I can call $4 (group 4) in the replacement string and it will insert a newline; Thats what I needed.

Comment: Also after some research I think i discovered that for .net flavour RegEx there is no ability to replace a matched string with another string, in pure Regex. So as I understand, you have to use RegEx to match your pattern and after it is matched, if you want to process it you likely will have to handle it programatically using c# methods/functions. Notepad++ does include more powerful RegEx library/definitions where you can find and replace strings in pure regex scripts.